# Does the YouTube API Geolocation Search Work?

Tags: youtube, geolocation, youtube-api

The [YouTube API documentation says that I should be able to search for videos by location](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#locationsp), within a specified radius.  This does not appear to work.

There is even an [official forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/youtube-api-gdata&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&parenturl=https://developers.google.com/youtube/forum/discussion#!searchin/youtube-api-gdata/location%2420radius%7Csort%3adate/youtube-api-gdata/93sFr3RQufg/bvef52cQaFQJ) showing how this can be done.

Yet calling a simple example like

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=json&location=51.5032025,-0.1273598!&location-radius=10km
```

Returns 0 results.

There should be *some* videos that tourists have uploaded of London!

So, is it still possible to get a list of videos tagged with location metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently working (tested on April 12, 2013). According to 
[GData issue 4234](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4234) "a change in the YouTube search index is preventing location-based searches from returning results"

The estimated fix is going to take longer than the mid-April 2013 time frame initially expected.

I eagerly anticipate the resolution. I'd suggest clicking the star on that issue page so you'll get updates when comments are added, etc.

**Update:** On April 16, 2013 the issue was updated stating "The current estimate is restoring this functionality in the second half of 2013." Also, their API documentation was updated to reflect the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Geolocation search is deprecated temporarily and expected to be up again in near future.
This was due to another launch, documentation is about to be refreshed. It will also be back up soon.

Comment: But if that were the case, surely Google would have put a notice on their documentation?  I don't think a company as large and well respected as Google would waste hours of developers' time with an unannounced deprecation - would they?

Comment: This was due to another launch, documentation is about to be refreshed. It will also be back up soon. As a side note, it's communicated regularly that there is less support on gdata api now, and everyone is encouraged to use YouTube Data APi v3.

Comment: The v3 API is listed as "experimental" - does that mean it's safe to use?  Or is it likely to be deprecated?  Additionally - there doesn't seem to be any way to search by geoloaction in v3.

Comment: It's safe to use. It's the one we are supporting heavily and we'll be. This functionality will be added to v3, not there yet. Also it will return to v2 in quite short time.

Comment: i disagree it's safe to use. I visit https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history, and i saw this line "The channel resource's snippet.channelId property has been removed. The resource's id property provides the same value." However, it's depends on your needs(when v3 provide feature you need which was impossible on v2)

Answer (score 0):

This is now working. See the [documentation for v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

```
# HTTP URL:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/?type=video
                                                 &locationRadius=100m
                                                 &location=51.5032025%2C-0.1273598
                                                 &part=snippet
                                                 &key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```